# Sending a http request through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an SMS API that I need to use to send a text message on a site that I'm building. There is a form on the website that collects a few details and the phone number, the message has to go to the phone number specified in the form.

The API link I have is:

> http://URL/api/v3/?method=sms&api_key=XXd9e5XXXXXXXXXXXXX&to=197XXXXXXX&sender=INFXXX&message=Welcome%20to%20messaging

How can I do this POST request using Ajax?

```
var formData = {
    'name': name,
    'location': location,
    'mobile': mobile
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true
})
```

This is what I use with the form on the site, can I use the same with this API?

Comment: depends on your api, read the documentation

Comment: As stated by @madalinivascu it depends on the your API. If you can provide the SMS gateway name may be someone will guide you in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In your upload.php file make a curl request like this:

upload.php:

```
$encodedMsg = urlencode($message);

$url = // url api url with mobile number and url emcoded message in it

// parameter to make a curl request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$APIresponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($APIresponse, true);

if($res['ErrorCode'] == '000')      // check for the response return by the API
{
    $response   = 'Success';
}
else
{
    $response   = 'Failed';
}

echo $response;

// Use this response in your ajax success function
```